# Merging two sorted arrays not working

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Trying to solve a problem involving merging two sorted arrays without using the sort method. Here's my code so far:

```
def combine(arr1, arr2)
result = []

i = 0
arr1.each do |num|
    while num > arr2[i] && arr2[i] != nil
        result << arr2[i]
        i += 1
    end
    result << num
end

result
end
```

When I run this with `[1, 9, 10, 12], [2, 5, 6, 8]` as the two arguments, it gives me a comparison of `Fixnum` to `nil` error and I can't wrap my head around it. It seems like an easy fix but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

```
while num > arr2[i] && arr2[i] != nil
```

You are using the wrong condition. According to the **short circuit** rule of `&&`, put the check for `nil` on the left:

```
while arr2[i] != nil && num > arr2[i]
```